# Scrolling animation in NavigationView

Tags: android, scroll, android-animation, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

My activity has a `NavigationView` inside a `DrawerLayout`.

When user clicks on a button in the NavigationView header, I would like to scroll to top the `DrawerLayout/NavigationView` with an animation.

It seems that NavigationView and DrawerLayout don't provide a method to get the actual scroll position (`getScrollY()` and `getScrollX()` always return 0) and so I can't do that.

How can I scroll to top with an animation?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <!-- My content -->

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: your `NavigationView` header is always at TOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to scroll the NavigationMenuView.

In the below code, it will scroll to top when click on any item in menu

```
 NavigationView navigationView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //here will scroll to top
((NavigationMenuView)navigationView.getChildAt(0)).smoothScrollToPosition(0);

        return true;
    }
```

EDIT: If you want to protect against possible changes down the road, you can use reflection here, like so:

```
// try to scroll to the top of the navigation menu, if possible
if (navigationView.getChildCount() > 0) {
    View childView = navigationView.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Method scroll = childView.getClass().getMethod("smoothScrollToPosition", int.class);
        scroll.invoke(childView, 0);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException |
            SecurityException |
            IllegalAccessException |
            InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "smoothScrollToPosition", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple user `smoothScrollToPosition(0)`  as `NavigationMenuView` is extend from `RecyclerView`

### see the [source code for NavigationMenuView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuView.java)

**e.g**

```
 navigationView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```